# R mssql Invalid Connection String

Tags: r, sql-server, docker, odbc, dbi

I have a docker container that contains a database which I'm able to access with the user id and password below and am running into an error when attempting to connect using this code:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                      Port = 1433,
                      Server = "localhost",
                      Database = "master",
                      UID = "sa",
                      PWD = "password!23")
```

The error is:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Computer specs:

> ```
> MacBook Pro (16-inch 2019)
> OS: macOS Monterey (version 12.2.1)
> Processor: 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
> Memory: 16GB 2667MHz DDR4
> Startup Disk: Macintosh HD
> Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB
> ```

Rstudio Version: 2021.09.0 Build 351

OpenSSL Version: 1.1

EDIT:

Switching the code such that the server references 127.0.0.1, 1433 fixed the latter error, but now I'm receiving the former:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
```

Code used to attempt to create connection:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                      server = "127.0.0.1,1433",
                      database = "master",
                      uid = "sa",
                      pwd = "password!23")
```

Docker command used to run the container:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=password!23' -p '1433:1433' --name sql3 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

Container attributes (`docker ps --no-trunc`):

```
CONTAINER ID                                                       IMAGE                                        COMMAND                                                   CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
f755291fe369f9ad3339626528999bb7cef3d7947e68045b60fc4591f865aace   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/nonroot_msg.sh /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr"   24 minutes ago   Up 41 seconds   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp   sql3
```

Comment: Remove `port`, use `server="127.0.0.1,1433"` (or just omit `port`, since 1433 is the default). It's often a problem using `localhost`, I recommend `127.0.0.1`. I don't think case is a concern, but I use lower-case argument names (`Driver=`, etc).

Comment: If you're not using JDBC (which is not ODBC), then I suggest the [tag:mssql] tag instead of [tag:mssql-jdbc].

Comment: Problems will arise if you are not starting the container with the correct exposed ports. To make sure, start the container with `docker -p "1433:1433" ...` and try again. (That is, if removing `port=` doesn't fix it first :-)

Comment: Hmmm, appending the port to the server parameter did get rid of the string attribute error, but I'm still sitting stuck with the first bit...

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection 

@r2evans: Good catch, though I actually figured that one out this morning. Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: Please include the command you used to start the docker container

Comment: I've included the docker command as well as the resulting container attributes in the update. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `"localhost"` yet?

Comment: Yeah, I've attempted switching out "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" and I'm still running into this error. Part of me is thinking that it might be due to upgrading to the latest MacOS (Monterey 12.2.1), but just wanted to ask before downgrading back to 11.x

Comment: Ahh, good question, and that component of your problem (macos) is not something I have access to troubleshoot. My spouse won't let me "dev" on her macbook :-/

Comment: From where is the R code executing? If it's executing on the host (in macOS) then `127.0.0.1,1433` should connect successfully. If it's executing inside another Docker container, however, try using `host.docker.internal,1433` instead. See this and other oddities at [Networking features in Docker Desktop for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have incontrovertible proof that it was Monterey 12.2.1 that was giving me problems, but downgrading to Big Sur 11.6.4 did resolve my issue (and gave me an opportunity to install dependencies in a more conscientious way).

Thanks everyone for your guidance!